# How to measure contents differences within lists

Tags: python, list, similarity, cosine-similarity

Don't want to cause confusion here. The reason I want a value attached with each list is I want to use contents within each list as a feature value for clustering algorithms. The original idea is I have 1000 items each with a list of company names. I want to transform this list contents into a value. That's why I want each value attached to each list as one of the features for this item.... Thanks.... (Also that's why I use a base list..)

I'm trying to use python to analyze some texts and now I have 1000 lists, each contains list of company names. For example:

```
list1 = ['google', 'facebook' 'twitter', 'IBM']
list2 = ['microsoft', 'bloomberg', '1010Data']
list3 = ['google', 'microsoft', '1010Data']
```

I want to measure these lists similarities. `list1` and `list2` has 0 similarities, but `list1` and `list3`, `list2` and `list3` have some similarities. But how to measure it?

Initially I thought about using one base vector which contains all the words from these lists. Here this base list could be:

```
base_list = ['google', 'facebook', 'twitter', 'IBM', 'microsoft', 'bloomberg','1010Data']
```

and its vector value is:

```
base_vector = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

Then each of these lists has vector values according to both the word appearance and its positions. 
(Here, `base_list`, `list1`, `list2`, `list3` are all sorted)

```
list1 = [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]
list2 = [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]
list3 = [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1]
```

I want to measure their differences (or similarities) by comparing each of them with the base_vector, to get the angle value.

But! A big issue could be

```
list1 = [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]
list2 = [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]
```

Then their angle value with the base vector are the same!

And suggestions? About how I can measure the similarities of the contents within lists? I mean I don't have to use this vector method, I just got blocked.

Thanks!

Comment: What should your input and output be? You could sort each list and then  compare corresponding locations.

Comment: why not compare the lists to each other, and the base_vector?

Comment: @corn3lius I thought of that but I have too many lists. I think at the end I'll have 12000 lists. If I compare with each other it's going to be O(N^2).

Comment: @neo Say I have 1000 lists. I want each list to have a value, input for this function is foo(v, v1) in which v is the base vector and v1 is list1's vector. And output should be a value. This goes on until all the lists have their corresponding value.

Comment: the problem with a base list is that similarity between (list1, base) says nothing about similarity between (list1, list2).

Comment: @BrunoCalza That's true..Then how should I assign these values to each list and use them as feature value for clustering?

Comment: @JudyJiang don't know. cause for each list you'll have a lot of similarity values. maybe you can combine them into a meaningful number

Answer (score 0):

You can use `numpy` to calculate the [cosine similarity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity) between lists:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> list2 = [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]
>>> list3 = [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1]
>>> angle = np.dot(list2,list3)/(np.linalg.norm(list2)*np.linalg.norm(list3))
>>> angle
0.66666666666666674
```

Alternativelly, you can use [scipy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/spatial.distance.html) and its spatial distances formulas like Manhattan, Euclidian, Jaccard. They are also metrics of similarity. Scipy also has the cosine similarity, which seems easier to use.

Comment: Yes. But I compare each list with the base_vector, which is [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]. If list2 is [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0] and list3 is [0, 0, 0, 1, 1,1] Then the value for base_vector and list1, base_vector and list3 are going to be the same.

Comment: This acutally makes sense, since both `list2` and `list3` are equally similar to the `base_vector`.

Comment: You don't compute similarity between a list and a base list. You compute similarities between lists. sim([1,1,1,0,0,0],[0,0,0,1,1,1]) results in 0.

Comment: @BrunoCalza But what if I have 10, 000 lists? I compare each of them?

Comment: If you compare the lists against each other, and they only contain ones and zeros, a sum of the xor'ed lists should do as a simliarity measure.

Answer (score 0):

I though of another solution using [Jaccard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaccard_index) similarity. You don't have to convert your lists into a numeric one using a base list as reference. Just apply the formula

```
>>> list1 = ['google', 'facebook' 'twitter', 'IBM']
>>> list2 = ['microsoft', 'bloomberg', '1010Data']
>>> list3 = ['google', 'microsoft', '1010Data']

>>> float(len(set(list2).intersection(list3)))/len(set(list2).union(list3))
0.5
```

Comment: But in this case I still have to compare list1 against with both list2 and list3, list2 against list3?

Comment: And what should be the value assigned to each list?

Comment: it depends on your need to store the similarity between all pairs of lists. if you do, you'll have to compare each one. i don't see an alternative

Comment: the value should be stored along with the pair (list1,list2)